# Why should we overload forwarding constructors for the case of initializer_list?

Tags: c++, c++17

`std::optional` provides constructors that forwards arguments to the constructor of the owned object:

```
 template<class...Args>
 optional(in_place_t,Args&&...args)
```

But it also provides this overload:

```
 template<class U,class...Args>
 optional(in_place_t,initializer_list<U> l,Args&&...args)
```

What are the benefits of this last overload?

Comment: Sorry about the closure; I thought you were asking something different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's to allow you to do this:

```
 optional<vector<int>> o(in_place_t, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
```

That's much shorter than:

```
 optional<vector<int>> o(in_place_t, std::initializer_list<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
```